# Using gpg on Aquamacs

Tags: encryption, emacs, gnupg, aquamacs

In the vanilla emacs we have an option to encrypt and decrypt files using the gpg encryption. I have emacs installed on MacOS Mojave and I use gpg to encrypt my password file.
Recently on seeing the supposed benefits of using Aquamacs, I encountered a problem while trying to decrypt my password file. It says no working gpg configuration found.
It works on emacs but not on Aquamacs.
Can some one help me out as to what is the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Did you know we have an apple specific board dedicated to Apple\Mac questions? https://apple.stackexchange.com/